# Redirect and render template with new variables

Tags: node.js, redirect, render, ejs

I will show my code first in order to be clear.

```
router.get("/add", (req, res)=>{
    res.render("user/add.ejs");
});

router.put("/add/pi", (req, res)=>{
    if(condition){
        //do something
    }else{
        res.redirect("/user/add");
        //res.render("user/add.ejs", {error: "At least one field should be filled in order to submit the form", type: "form error","location": "form-container"});
    }
});
```

Ejs:

```
<% if(error){ %>
    <small id="personalinformationError" class="form-text text-danger"><%= error %></small>
<% }%>
```

I want to be able to render the ejs template with the object in the `render()` in the comment. I tried to render it like in the comment without `redirect()` and it shows an error whenever I mention the variable name. The error goes like `variable is not defined`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "whenever I mention the variable name". Which variable?

Comment: the `error`, `type` and `location` variables that are in the comment

Comment: `error`, `type` and `location` are not variables but fields of the params object you are passing to the render function

Comment: When i call them in my ejs file, it shows the error if i render from the PUT route

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the error was shown by Node. I have never used EJS but the problem may be on that side. Post the code you're using to access the variables so it's easy for someone to help you.